# java - public static String get "reference"

Tags: java, string, static, public

I don't understand something regarding the public static Strings. I have a couple of
variables that need to be accessed globaly (I know that that is not the true OO approach).
If I pass the "reference" of public static String str from Globals class, any change made to the value in SomeClass will not update
that variable.

```
    public class Globals{

    public static String str;

    }

    public class SomeClass{

    private String str;

    public void setStr(String str){
        this.str = str; 
        //If I change the value of str in this SomeClass, the value does not get
        //updated for the public static String str in Globals class
    }

//Here assign new value for str

    }
```

Comment: Why would you imagine that the two `str` fields (the one in `Globals` and the one in `SomeClass`) were related? Can you give us your `setStr()` invocation as well?

Answer (score 4):

Your scope is ambiguous. Did you mean this:

```
public void setStr(String str){
    this.str = str; 
    //If I change the value of str in this SomeClass, the value does not get
    //updated for the public static String str in Globals class
   Globals.str = this.str;
}
```

or this:

```
public void setStr(String str){
    this.str = str; 
    //If I change the value of str in this SomeClass, the value does not get
    //updated for the public static String str in Globals class
    this.str = Globals.str;
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Technically, the scope is _not_ ambiguous. Java scoping rules require that, without additional cope indicators like `this` or `ClassName` or `classInstance`, the smallest scoped variable with the given name be used. That said, your examples _do_ make the distinction more clear.

Comment: Agreed. I meant the question was ambiguous, as in I wasn't sure which scope the OP wanted to make use of.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are not calling the "global" `str` variable, but instead are calling the class-local `str` variable.

Without additional information about what `str` variable you are wanting to change, Java will use the most tightly-scoped variable with the given name. Just like you did with `this.str` in the constructor to indicate you wanted the private instance variable of the `SomeClass` class, you would need to do `Globals.str` to indicate you wanted the `public static str` variable that you are using as a global.

Also, as others have pointed out, `String`s are immutable in Java, so what you are really doing when you assign to any variable of type `String` is changing the `String` the variable is referencing.

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys - Good point. I miss-read the code sample initially. I have corrected my answer to reflect this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The str class variable is declared statically for the Globals class not for every class in an application. The str in Someclass has no relation to the str in Globals - they just happen to have the same identifier.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in Java parameters are passed by value, not reference. Thus, assigning a new value to the `String` object is not seen outside the method. You can use a wrapper to achieve this:

```
class StringWrapper {
    public String value;
}

public void setString(StringWrapper wrapper) {
    wrapper.value = "some value"; // the String inside wrapper is changed
}
```

Comment: That's only true for primitives Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @twain249, no, objects aren't passed at all. (References to objects are passed though, but those are also by value.)

Comment: The reference to the `String` is still passed by value. Assigning a different reference to a `String` parameter will not be seen outside.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Globals{

public static String str;

}

public class SomeClass{

private String str;

}
```

Those 2 strings are not the same string (you should change one of their names). To access the `str` in Globals you'll have to use `Globals.str`. Also Strings are immutable so you don't actually change the string but create a new string and assign the value to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable.

You're passing a reference to an immutable `String` instance, not to the mutable `str` variable.

Comment: Strings might indeed be immutable but it has no bearing in this case.

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys: He might think that he's mutating the existing instance.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
this.str = str;
```

To:

```
Globals.str = str;
```